# How to integrate Google tag manager + Firebase in a cordova app ?

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic2, google-tag-manager, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to integrate the google tag manager to my Cordova based project. 
Integrating the firebase was easy because there is a plugin available that manages the firebase https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

All the guides from google are meant for the native apps and not for hybrid apps, integrating tag manager in a hybrid app seems to be a question with no good answer so far, because if you try to treat the app as a webview it will most of the times give you errors.

Any suggestions on how to integrate Google Tag Manager in a hybrid app ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your plugin does support google tag manager but only for Android for now. And it is not "officially" supported by your plugin as far as I know.

[Here is the google-tag-manager sdk for android in your plugin](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/6afd92e48aa2a81d10a1d9e3732162b78f4ed724/plugin.xml#L59)

Setup your google tag manager with an Android container (important) then download your json file and add the resource-file path to your config.xml.

```
<platform name="android">
        <content src="index.html" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/containers/GTM-5MFXXXX.json" target="assets/containers/GTM-5MFXXXX.json" />
```

[here is the documentation of it](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/6afd92e48aa2a81d10a1d9e3732162b78f4ed724/README.md#google-tag-manager) .. yeah I know there isn't more

Check after building the app with cordova if the json file is in the correct folder.

root 
-- src 
-- node_modules 
-- platform
---- Android
------ assets 
-------- img 
-------- containers 
----------> **gtm.json** 
---- etc

If you wanna make sure that your google tag manager works, start your Android Studio Debugger and check the logs with logcat.

You should see something like this.

```
16:01:03.742 9748-9776/XXX I/GoogleTagManager: Loading container GTM-XXXXXX
16:01:03.750 9748-9776/XXX I/GoogleTagManager: Installing Tag Manager event handler.
16:01:03.757 9748-9776/XXX I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager event handler installed.
16:01:03.757 9748-9776/XXX I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 28ms
16:01:05.502 9748-9882/XXX I/GoogleTagManager: Obtained fresh AdvertisingId info from GmsCore.
```

Your firebase sdk does the rest! This should get the whole thing running

Comment: Was able to get this working on Android. Any help with iOS (I realize this was a long time ago)?

Comment: In the meanwhile the community maintained version of Firebase does support Google Tag Manager for iOS as well as Android!

I would recommend to check it out as it is easier for you. [cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/GOOGLE_TAG_MANAGER.md)

Comment: Thats the plugin I am using but it does not work on iOS. Have you seen it working on iOS? I do not see the GoogleTagManager framework included in their plugin.xml either. I tried adding it myself but have run into many build errors and conflicts.

Comment: I got it working back then but we never went live with it because it was not demanded anymore from the client

Comment: Good to know and thanks for your help. Do you remember if you had to do anything special to get it working on iOS?

Comment: If I remember correctly I installed the cocoapods manually (which are needed for google-tag-manager) to get it working.. but it was a long time ago so not sure if this helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working myself. I initially tried using `cordova-plugin-firebase` which supports Android GTM out-of-the-box but requires an extra pod/framework to be added for iOS. I could not ever get the extra pod or framework to build with that plugin.

So I switched to using a forked version of `cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics` which already uses pods for all of its Firebase dependencies. Check out the plugins GTM branch on their GitHub page and look in the commit history to see what changes need to be made to your fork.

https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics/tree/gtm

And thanks to the other answer from Enes Yalçın for the help.

Comment: For this, We need to move the GTM configuration file to container folder Using hook. unfortunately it is not working. can any one tell how we proceed

Comment: @VenkaTeshuser5397700 GTM will find the config file if its in the root or in the container folder. Either should work.

Comment: phonegap build is not support hook. any other way to move file into root